# Как добавить в DbContext строку подключения из App.config?

Tags: c#, база-данных

У меня есть вот такой контекст:

```
public class OtvetContext : DbContext
    {
        public OtvetContext(DbContextOptions<OtvetContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<OtvetGet> Otvets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Shipment> Shipment { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Item> Item { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Discount> Discount { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Event> Event { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Goodsdata> Goodsdata { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\SberApi\\SberApi\\SberDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

И есть вот такой App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SberDB" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\source\repos\SberApi\SberApi\DBSber.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Как мне подставить строку подключения в мой DbContext? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Конструктор добавьте для начала, который будет принимать DbContextOptions

Comment: Добавил(в самом вопросе код тоже отредактировал), что дальше?

Comment: А дальше надо при создании контекста этот самый настроенный options ему передавать.

Comment: А как это сделать? Сможете код написать пожалуйста?